# What is the most stable pear-shaped nucleus?

Tags: radioactivity, nuclear

I have heard on the Internet that there are at least three pear-shaped nuclei: radium-224, radon-220 (a direct product of the previous isotope), and barium-144. CERN has a webpage about this discovery https://home.cern/news/news/experiments/first-observations-short-lived-pear-shaped-atomic-nuclei and it calls them "short-lived". Their half-lives are all less than one week and I wonder if radium-224 is the most stable pear-shaped nucleus or if there are more stable ones that have that property in common.

Comment: Probably better on Physics SE. Even as a long-time supporter of Glen Seaborg's nuclear chemistry contributions, this one really is nuclear physics.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about chemistry.